# Select2 4.0 - initialize with tag not in data list

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a multiple select Select2 (v4.0) item initialized as such:

```
$('select#testselect2').select2({
    multiple: true,
    tags: true
});
```

There is no data source, it's completely dependent on the user entering their own multiple values. They can enter user-defined values and save back to the DB, no problem.

When retrieving from the DB, though, I'm unable to set the Select2's value to contain the user-defined values. I've tried using **$(...).val(arrayObject).trigger('change')** to no avail. I've been unable to find another solution in the documentation.

If I define some options in the select element, then use the **val** method above with an array containing some values defined as options AND values *not* defined in options, it will only display the option values and not the "tag" ones.
For example, this select:

```
<select id="testselect2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and this code:

```
$('select#testselect2').val(['1','2','5']).trigger('change');
```

...will produce "1" and "2" as the selected values.

How do I set the Select2's selected values to entries that are not in the options / data source?

Comment: I have the same issue as well, in case you came up with a solution by now.

Comment: I create an issue using your case on Github: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4126